Probability of flipping coins with advantage
I am flipping a coin, for that flip i'm allowed to flip two coins instead and use one of those results as that coin flip. (1 - (1/(2^2^1))) = 75% of calling the flip right.
I continue flipping a coin using this rule until I fail, so my odds of getting three in a row are 0.75 * 0.75 * 0.75 = 42.18%
If I flip a coin, I instead flip two coins and ignore one. I keep flipping a coin until I lose the flip, then I flip a coin until I lose the flip.
Failing a call moves to the next iteration of flipping.
In this example there are two independent iterations of me flipping until I lose the call.
What are my odds of getting at least three successful flips with both iterations combined?

How can you get "three in a row" from just "two instances of flipping this way"? It's very unclear what you're asking. Please edit the question to make it clear.

I'm allowed to keep flipping until I fail, then when I fail I can start flipping again until I fail.
Each one of these "flipping until I fail" is an instance. Two in this case.

@user1346840 Aren't these two instances independent? Why can't you just simply multiply 42.18 % by itself?

For what it's worth, virtually every MathSE posted question that I have seen, that followed this article on MathSE protocol has been upvoted rather than downvoted.  I am not necessarily advocating this protocol.  Instead, I am merely stating a fact: if you scrupulously follow the linked article, skipping/omitting nothing, you virtually guarantee a positive response.

@Kandinskij updated question. I need a combined total of at least three successful flips over the two instances. Not three in a row on both.

Pl put your above comment in the body of the question for self-contained clarity, comments can go unread.

You search : probability of AT LEAST one success. It is very often simpler to search : probability of 2 failures. Probability of 2 failures is $0.5782^2$ ; So probability of at least 1 success is $1-0.5782^2$

To simplify the description, let's suppose you always call heads. So you flip two coins and if at least one comes up heads, that's one success. If they both come up tails that's a failure. So are you saying you want to know the chance that you'll get at least one head on three separate occasions when you flip both coins, if you're allowed to flip two tails up to two times before the third time you flip at least one head?

@DavidK The first instance could have two successful calls, then the second instance could have none. The first instance could also have one successful call and the second instance could have two etc. Both could have zero successful calls in a row. I'm wondering what the odds of getting at least three successful flips are combined on both instances.

@DavidK And they don't all need to be in a row.
first instance: successful call, successful call, failed call.
second instance: successful call, failed call.
These two instances would count as three.

I don't understand why you use the word "instance." It also isn't clear what happened in each "instance" in the last comment. The way I read your question, the first "instance" could happen like this: You call heads, you flip two coins, result HT, first successful call. You call tails, you flip two coins, result TT, second successful call. You call tails again, you flip two coins, result HH, failed call. Is that a valid example? If not, what is? Explain using the same explicit amount of detail I just did.

@DavidK Yes that would be a good example of one iteration.
I guess its more of a iteration inside a loop than a instance.
Flip a coin until you lose the flip, then flip the coin until you lose the flip.
If you would flip a coin, instead flip two coins and ignore one.

@DavidK Rephrased the question. Not sure how to make it any clearer at my level of math.

I'm sorry to see that the question has been downvoted after you put so much work into it. (I consider that for someone just starting in probability to be able to ask a question like this coherently is more than enough effort to put into a question.) At least I think I understood it well enough now to write an answer.

Let's use the word "advantage" from the question title.
Define a flip with advantage as a procedure in which you call heads or tails,
then you flip two coins and keep only the best of the two coins' results.
If the result you keep is what you called, we say you called the flip with advantage correctly.
For example, suppose you call heads, the first coin shows a tail, and the second coin shows a head. Then we say you called the flip with advantage correctly.
But if you call heads and both coins show tails, we say you called the flip with advantage incorrectly.
So the probability to call one flip with advantage correctly is $\frac34$ (that is, $75\%$). And the probability to call three consecutive flips with advantage all correctly with no incorrect calls is $\left(\frac34\right)^3 = \frac{27}{64} = 0.421875.$
That is, both of these probabilities are computed correctly in the question.
Now you want to call flips with advantage until you call one incorrectly,
and then again call flips with advantage until you call one incorrectly.
That is, you will flip with advantage until you have called incorrectly twice,
and after the second incorrect call you will stop.
You want to know the probability of calling at least three of the flips with advantage correctly.
The probability is the same as the probability that if you call four flips with advantage, you will call at least three of them correctly.
That's because you have to get three correct calls before the second incorrect call.
It's OK to have one incorrect call mixed in with the three correct ones, but if you have two incorrect calls before you get the third correct one, you have "failed".
So we're looking for cases where the third correct call happens on either the third or fourth flip with advantage.
We can reduce this to two cases:

Four correct calls in the first four flips with advantage. The probability of this is $\left(\frac34\right)^4 = \frac{81}{256}$.

Three correct calls and one incorrect call. Any particular sequence of three correct and one incorrect has probability $\frac14\left(\frac34\right)^3$,
but there are four possible sequences (the incorrect call can be any of the four flips with advantage), so the probability of this case is $4\times \frac14\left(\frac34\right)^3 = \frac{27}{64}$.


The total probability of success is therefore
$$ \frac{81}{256} + \frac{27}{64} = \frac{189}{256} = 0.73828125. $$

Thanks for your help I appreciate it. This is exactly the answer I was looking for. Just hard to put into words with only software engineering background and not one in mathematics.
